# Iterating through enumerate returns strings in brackets

Tags: python

I have list of teams and I wanted to actually put them in a database but I have problem looping with enumerate

So this the list

```
teams = [
        ('Team1', '91'),
        ('Team2', '89'),
        ('Team3', '87')
        ]
```

I first tried out this and simple for loop and no problem with it.

```
for name, num in teams:
    print (name,num)
```

returns

```
Team1 91
Team2 89
Team3 87
```

Then I wanted to add some bit of format and tried out enumerate

```
for name, num in enumerate(teams, start=1):
    print("{}. {} Pts".format(name, num))
```

returns

```
1. ('Team1', '91') Pts
2. ('Team2', '89') Pts
3. ('Team3', '87') Pts
```

Why does it return with brackets, quotes e.t.c. and while the other one is not? or am missing something? I am fairly new to python by the way.

My expected ouput is this

```
1. Team1 91 Pts
2. Team2 89 Pts
3. Team3 87 Pts
```

Comment: [Those are tuples.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: and what should I use then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
for i, (name, num) in enumerate(teams, start=1):
    print("{}. {} {} Pts".format(i, name, num))
```

enumerate returns the index (1-3 in this case) and each value of the iterable (teams in this case).  The values returned from the iterable will be tuples.  You can expand the tuple as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

The `enumerate()` function adds a counter to an iterable so your `num` is still each item in your array (i.e. the tuple).

```
teams = [
    ('Team1', '91'),
    ('Team2', '89'),
    ('Team3', '87')
]

for index, item in enumerate(teams, start=1):
    print("{}. {} {} Pts".format(index, item[0], item[1]))
```